Multiple application API authentication with single ASP.NET Core server
We have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API using JWT-based authentication. We have an endpoint /api/customer/signup to create sign up new users.
We used built-in identity server in ASP.NET Core for authentication. Initially our back-end was supposed to serve the requirement of our company only.
But now we need to modify it in a way so that we can provide the APIs to multiple other applications so that they can use it.
Let's say there is a companyA and companyB. They implemented our API. If any customer signs up for companyA, then he/she won't be able to sign up for companyB with the same email address.
Is there any better way to solve this problem?

But if both use the same "sign up" endpoint, which means they are using the same identity database. So of course you cannot register with same email to this database. Why is this a problem?

@QiangFu Thanks for the response, I'm looking for a solution where they will be using same api endpoint but user will register as new user if company is different. that means. if I have an email address abc@example.com, I'll be able to sign up for companyA and companyB. There will be 2 account.

You could add additional field to UserModel
    public class CustomUser :IdentityUser
    {
        public string? Company { get; set; } 
    }

Since UserManager.CreateAsync using defualt uservalidator which will check deputlicated UserName to prevent from registering ,We need to create a CustomUserManger and override the CreateAsync.
CustomUserManager.cs
    public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<CustomUser>
    {
        public CustomUserManager(IUserStore<CustomUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<CustomUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<CustomUser>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<CustomUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<CustomUser>> logger) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
        {
        }

        public override Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(CustomUser user)
        {
            //we need to clear the default validators here and use 
            UserValidators.Clear();
            UserValidators.Add(new CustomUserIdentityValidator());

            return base.CreateAsync(user);
        }
    }

CustomUserIdentityValidator.cs
    internal sealed class CustomUserIdentityValidator : IUserValidator<CustomUser>
    {
        public async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<CustomUser> manager, CustomUser user)
        {

            //Find all users with the registered email.
            var users =  manager.Users.Where(x => x.Email == user.Email);

            //check if the same email company user has been registered.
            if (users.Any(x=>x.Company==user.Company))
            {
                return IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError { Description="depulicated email in same company"});
            }

            return IdentityResult.Success;
        }
    }

Then in program.cs configure the customUserManger
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<CustomUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddUserManager<CustomUserManager>();

When company A or B making request to api, they should add a header named "company". Then in the backend api, you could get this header information and add to Company field of CustomUser.
            var company = HttpContext.Request.Headers["company"];
            var user = new CustomUser()
            {
                Email = "input Email",
                UserName = "input userName",
                Company = company
            };
            var result=await _customUserManager.CreateAsync(user,"input password");

